# Trying to retrieve names from 'name column' from two different tables

Tags: laravel, database-design

I am trying to pull the names columns from the `categories` table and the `brands` table. The `brand_user` table is the bridge/pivot table between the `brands` and `users` so I can pull brands based on a user's id.

The problem is my output only gives the `categories` name column in the results and the `brands` name is omitted. I've tried doing left and right joins and the issue persists. It doesn't seem I should have to call the `brands` name column `brand_name` and the categories name column `category_name`, but at this moment that is the only solution I can think of but would rather not if possible (and if it makes sense to not).

So my question is, should I make the name columns unique to each table, or can I use `name` as the generic name column for tables that would use it?

```
return DB::table('brands')
            ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'brands.category_id')    
            ->join('brand_user', 'brand_user.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
            ->select('brands.name', 'categories.name')
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are interested in Eloquent and Laravel way and you already have a many to many relationship between brand and user and one to many relationship between brand and category in place, you can iterate through brands and categories this way.

```
$brands = Brand::whereHas('users', function($query) {
        $query->where('users.id', auth()->id());
    })
    ->with('category')
    ->get();

foreach($brands as $brand) {
    echo $brand->name .' ' .$brand->category->name;
}
```

You can look for more details of Eloquent relationship here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thanks for the response! This seems to be along the lines of what I was hoping for. I copy/pasted what you have here and get an error that `=>` should be `)` I will look a bit deeper into the documentation.

Comment: @DarrylHardin right, I mix up js and php syntax sometimes. sorry about that, changed =>  to ,

Answer (score 0):

It appears I can just add an alias for those and it takes care of the ambiguous column name issue.

```
return DB::table('brands')
            ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'brands.category_id')    
            ->join('brand_user', 'brand_user.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')
            ->select('brands.name as bName', 'categories.name as cName')
            ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Any other answers that have different ways to do this, or maybe better ways with Laravel would be appreciated.